# A different rubygem version for each ruby version in rvm

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 installed by rvm. For each ruby version, I'd like to:

- use gem 1.3.7 for ruby 1.8.7
- use gem 1.8.x for ruby 1.9.3

How can I set the above in rvm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When install rvm and then rvm install ruby --version its taken latest rubygems version. So just follow the below steps:

1. `rvm use 1.8.7`
2. `gem -v`, e.g. shows `1.8.24` like that
   If you want to use rubygems particular version only follow steps #3 and #4.
   This is for syntax set the rubygems in rvm
3. `rvm rubygems [x.y.z|latest-x.y|latest|remove]`
   Ex like this:
   Retrieving rubygems-1.3.7

   ```
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                            Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   100  284k  100  284k    0     0  94166      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  125k
   Extracting rubygems-1.3.7 ...
   Removing old Rubygems files...
   Installing rubygems-1.3.7 for ruby-1.8.7-p371 ...
   Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
   ```

   then
4. `gem -v` => It shows 1.3.7
5. `rvm rubygems 1.3.7`

And If you want use any other version go to step #3

Ex: `rvm rubygems latest`

Answer (score 6):

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7
$ rvm rubygems 1.3.7
$ rvm use 1.9.3
$ rvm rubygems latest-1.8
$ gem -v
1.8.24
$ rvm use 1.8.7
$ gem -v
1.3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created gemsets in rvm for 1.3.7 and 1.8.x, skip this step.  Otherwise, you need to create the gemset.

Here is how to create a gemset and then switch to it:
rvm 1.8.7                 # switch to ruby 1.8.7
rvm gemset create 1.3.7   # you may have to do it this way: rvm --force rubygems 1.3.7 
rvm gemset use 1.3.7      # use it

Next time you want to use ruby 1.8.7 with gemset 1.3.7 you only need to do this:
rvm use 1.8.7@1.3.7       # this sets the ruby version and gem version
ruby -v                   # checks the ruby version, should = 1.8.7
gem --version             # checks the gemset version, should = 1.3.7

Repeat this for ruby 1.9.3 and gemset 1.8.x.

You can find out how to do this and find answers to questions other rvm related topics here: http://rvm.io/gemsets/using